# error when trying to get value from function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a react component where I'm importing a function from another file like this:

```
import documentIcons from '/documentIcons';
```

Then I'm trying to use that function like this:

```
let file = this.state.selectedFile;  //this returns fine
let fileExt = file.name.split('.').pop();   //this also works
let fileIcon = documentIcons(fileExt);   //this throws the error
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

The documentIcons.js file looks like this:

```
const icons= {
  "jlr": "/icn/typeA.png",
  "trr": "/icn/typeB.png",
  "bpx": "/icn/typeC.png",
};

export const documentIcons = (f) => {
  this.icons.find(f)
}
```

I'm passing in a file extension(jlr, trr, or bpx) and I want the path to that icon returned.

Is there a way to do this in react/es6?

Thanks!

Comment: `export default` instead of `export`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `documentIcons` is a [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_named_exports), and should be [imported as one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_single_export_from_a_module):

```
import { documentIcons } from '/documentIcons'
```

The other option is to change the named export to a [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export):

```
const documentIcons = (f) => {
    this.icons.find(f) // this error is handled below
}

export default documentIcons
```

You should also remove the `this` from the method, since `icons` is a constant in the scope, and not a property on the same object. An object doesn't have the `find` method, and you should use brackets notation to get the value, and then return it:

```
const documentIcons = (f) => icons[f]
```

Comment: Hi thanks, that took care of the 1st error.  No I'm seeing this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icons' of undefined for this line : this.icons.find(f)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of missing parts here.

First of all export your function with default or import it as a named one:

```
import { documentIcons } from "/documentIcons";
```

Second one, you can't use `.map` on an object. If you want to find the url with the object key, use it like this:

```
icons[f]
```

Third, your are not returning anything from your function. Use it like this:

```
export const documentIcons = (f) => icons.[f];
```

This is a shorthand for:

```
export const documentIcons = (f) => {
    return icons.[f]
}
```